# PHP: Echoing Variables Error

Tags: php

Goal: To display a category select-box and its corresponding subcategory select-box. MySQL table is set up to have id(primary key), master_id(referencing on the primary key) and name. I set 4 error code blocks and after debugging i keep getting "error 2:true". Thus, displaying a category but no subcategory.  How come i keep getting this error? Is there something missing?

**PHP comparing category&value to display on the subcategory selectbox**

```
if (!empty($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['value'])) {

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $value = $_GET['value'];

    try {
        $objDb = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $db, $user, $pass);


        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `master_id`=?";
        $statement = $objDb->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute(array($value));
        $list = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say `master_id` in your question but you have `master` in your query.

Comment: "change" and "to" code examples are identical. Type of placeholder changes nothing

Comment: @LawrenceChereone That fixed it. Thank you! I feel like a fool after struggling 2 hours lol.